# Transforming and identity for $n \choose k$ with the "committee and chair" trick

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am not sure if this equality has a more formal name, but it is informally called the "committee and chair" trick from Ross. It is: $$k {m \choose k} = m {m-1 \choose k-1}$$

I saw it applied in the following manner, and am confused by the transformation. It is: $$ {N \choose n} = {N \over n} {N-1 \choose n-1}$$

It would seem that $k=n/n=1$ in the first choose factor. But why does $m=N/n$? It would seem that it should be $m=N/N$ to me, but clearly that isn't correct.

Comment: This is just a matter of renaming $m$ to $N$ and $k$ to $n$, and dividing both sides by $n$.

Comment: @Travis Yes, thanks. That is painfully obvious now. For some reason I was having trouble seeing the division. Consider posting that as an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: You're welcome, it happens to the best of us. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a matter of renaming $m$ to $n$ and $k$ to $n$, and then dividing both sides by $n$.